# Setting Javascript along with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm developing an HTML page with JQuery script within it and this page has a form that submits to a PHP page.

I was asked to add a JavaScript code to enable\disable textboxes based on a drop down list options, so after I've added that, the page is not redirecting anymore and it is telling me when submitting to the php page that the HTML is malformed.

This is the encoding I have

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

My question is what is the best place to plug the JS script? does it have to be inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

or I can add it anywhere I want in the document which causing the HTML to not be interpreted correctly by the server.

Comment: What has character encoding of the page to do with the placement of the script?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Typically you want to place all `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page.  Yes, you can add javascript inside your `$(document).ready` function.  jQuery IS javascript. But it definitely has to be in a `<script>` tag somewhere.

Comment: Gary can you post an example in the comments please?

Comment: `<script> $(document).ready(function() {..});</script> </body>` I think is what he is getting at. You want to add your script tags just before the closing `<body>` tags. This lets the browser render the page before running the Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: stuff your .ready() call in the `<head>`, **AFTER** the `<script>` that loads jquery itself.

Comment: @Press  Exactly. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, with script tags just before closing body tags. You can put it inside the head and other places but must be enclosed in `<script>` tags.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

        <script src="libs/jquery/jquery.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
                    // do something
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used the same thing as here and it is still showing the encoding problem when redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Example from comment above:

```
<head>
  .....
</head>
<body>
<!-- html code here -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
     // code to disable drop downs here
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your JS in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Lorem ipsum, blah foo bar.
    <script>

      // same as $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function() {
        // put your enable/disable dropdowns jQuery code here
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If your JS script doesn't need jQuery, (uses queries ex: `$('.dropdown a')`) then you can exclude the `$(function() {` wrap